# Offending RSA key in /u/.ssh/known_hosts during git clone on windows

Tags: windows, git, ssh

I am trying to git clone a repository on my windows machine, with:

```
git clone -b <branch> ssh://<host>
```

I have already added the keys, and deleted the existing known_hosts file in C:\Users<username>.ssh

But the git clone fails with

```
@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@
@    WARNING: REMOTE HOST IDENTIFICATION HAS CHANGED!     @
@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@
IT IS POSSIBLE THAT SOMEONE IS DOING SOMETHING NASTY!
Someone could be eavesdropping on you right now (man-in-the-middle attack)!
It is also possible that a host key has just been changed.
The fingerprint for the DSA key sent by the remote host is
SHA256:<fingerprint>.
Please contact your system administrator.
Add correct host key in /u/.ssh/known_hosts to get rid of this message.
Offending RSA key in /u/.ssh/known_hosts:6
```

Where is this known_hosts (/u/.ssh/known_hosts) file? C:\Users<username>\.ssh does not have this file, I was expecting for it to get created in the git clone command.

The same command works fine on my ubuntu PC.

Comment: Do you run your ` git clone ...` command from a specific shell (e.g: `git-bash`) ? have you tried running `ls /u/.ssh` from that shell ?

Comment: Git just runs ssh; this complaint comes from ssh, not from Git. The one complication here is that Git-for-Windows comes with *its own* ssh implementation, in case you're lacking one or the one you have is defective, so that on Windows, you can't be sure *which* ssh Git is running: the native one that came with your Windows system, or the auxiliary one that came with Git-for-Windows. Figure that out and you'll have your answer, or at least, the correct question with which to find your answer.

Comment: @LeGEC, you are correct. I am new to git on windows, hence I made this mistake. I got the path from git bash. But the original command was run with git cmd, so I thought it should take the ssh config from C:\Users\....\.ssh. Thanks a lot for the help!

Comment: @torek, yes, you are correct. With LeGEC 's input, I was able to figure the correct location. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The mentioned path has an linux-ish look, which indicates you were probably running your command from `git-bash`.

The simplest way to fix your issue is to edit the mentioned file (`/u/.ssh/known_hosts`) from a `git-bash` shell.

Answer (score 1):

Check your environment variable `HOME`: in a CMD, type `set HOME`.

If it is set to `U:\` (translated, in a bash session, to `/u/`), that would explain why SSH is lookig for information (keys, config file, known_hosts file, ...) in `U:\.ssh`

Change your `HOME` environment variable (back to, for instance, `%USERPROFILE%`) to make sure SSH looks for keys where you expect it.